# Accessing a public field of a java class from Kotlin

Tags: kotlin

I am trying to switch to Kotlin from Java. But I have a lot of legacy code and third-party libraries. And I see that pretty often there are public fields without getters and setters in Java classes that must be accessed from other classes.
How can I access a public field of a Java class without getter from Kotlin code?

Comment: you can access directly to the property

Answer (score 1):

you can **access directly** to the property
can you add min code example ?
for this example i cant seem to understand what is the problem

**Test.java**

```
public class Test {

    public int myPublicValue = 7;
}
```

**Runner.kt**

```
fun main(args: Array<String>) {

    val t = Test()
    t.myPublicValue
}
```